# Missing ContentController registration in asp.net mvc while using custom ControllerFactory with unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, unity-container

I'm using custom controller factory with unity to create a controller instances. My factory looks like:

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string  controllerName)
    {            
        return IoC.Container.Resolve<BaseController>(controllerName + "Controller");
    }

....
```

When I'm debugging this code it is trying to resolve **ContentController** (controllerName == "Content"), wich is of course not registered in my unity configuration file. I have tried to find if the **ContentController** exists somewhere in the System.Web.MVC, but I didnt find it.

Can somebody explain to me, why this factory is trying to resolve this controller?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, but it sounds like static content from your website in the `Content` folder (e.g images, css, etc) is being served via MVC, when it shouldn't.

What server are you using? If your using IIS 7 or IIS Express, it should used the managed pipeline and thus requests of these types shouldn't even get to the MVC runtime.

Try digging deeper into the `requestContext` instance to see exactly what is requesting this controller.

Comment: thanks for the tip with the analyzing requestContext. I have found, that there was a request to a css file which was not on the disk. I have forgot to remove this reference from the View. So probably, when the IIS not found this file, then it tried to use MVC. I'm running on Windows 7 Ultimate. I'm not sure which version of IIS is there installed by default.